# Importing packages from other project in java

Tags: java

I want to import packages that my friend created for his project to my project. What should I do to import that package. Do I have to create library file and include those in my project ?

Comment: Could you potentially expand on this problem a bit?

Comment: I have a folder in my desktop with foldername my and it contains 4 java classes. How can I import this package in my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
import   <the complete package name>
```

like

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
```

if you want to do static import than:

```
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
```

Do you need something else?

Comment: @user2850601 create a jar out of the class files and put in the class path than you can import as i have shown.

Comment: Where should I put that package. He just send me a folder that has all classes. Where to copy that folder.

Comment: @user2850601 otherwise you can do one thing you can create the same hierarchy (create folders) in your project i.e. packages and copy those corresponding files in side the folders. And you are done. Suppose his package is com.xyz.file than you can see some folder structure com than xyz. So create same inside your project. got it?

Comment: can you explain little bit more. To be specific he send me a folder name my with four java file. How can I include that package in my project.

Comment: @want2learn can you pls read out the first line of the file which says about the package.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the external jars in the classpath and then you will be able to `import` the classes they provide.

```
import fully.qualified.class.name.from.external.jar.ClassName;
```

Comment: can you please explain more with examples.

Answer (score 0):

packagee line should be a first line of you program.
  if you want load all classes of package the use below line.

```
import packagename.*;
```

if you want to import single class of package use

```
import packagename.classname;
```